# Send JSON with array field via cURL

Tags: curl

I'm trying to send the following via curl:

```
{ "groupsEnabled":["info"] }
```

JSON with a field which contains an array which contains one element. I tried the following:

```
curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:3030/log -d 'groupsEnabled[]=info'
```

Results in:

```
{ 'groupsEnabled[]': 'info' }
```

I tried to follow the other posts but they were over complicated.

Answer (score 0):

The cURL command (using http://httpbin.org/post as an example) is:

```
$ curl -X POST -d "{'groupsEnabled':['info']}"  -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://httpbin.org/post
```

http://httpbin.org/post displays the request:

```
{
  "args": {},
  "data": "{'groupsEnabled':['info']}",
  "files": {},
  "form": {},
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "*/*",
    "Content-Length": "26",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Host": "httpbin.org",
    "User-Agent": "curl/7.49.0"
  },
  "json": null,
  "origin": "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx",
  "url": "http://httpbin.org/post"
}
```

The part your interested in is

```
"data": "{'groupsEnabled':['info']}",
```

If you want double quotes not single quotes you will have to escape which will be dependant on your OS.